# dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/rpc.statd

Tags: ubuntu, rpc

In Ubuntu 22.04(Jammy) there are two rpc.statd binaries exist with hardlink. If main file /sbin/rpc.statd is there, what is the use case of hardlinked file /usr/sbin/rpc.statd. Thank you.

```
:~# dpkg -S /sbin/rpc.statd
nfs-common: /sbin/rpc.statd

:~# dpkg -S /usr/sbin/rpc.statd
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/rpc.statd

:~# ll -i /sbin/rpc.statd /usr/sbin/rpc.statd
73696 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 80944 Oct 20  2022 /sbin/rpc.statd*
73696 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 80944 Oct 20  2022 /usr/sbin/rpc.statd*
```

Comment: backward compatibility with tools that expect `rpc.statd` to be in `/usr/sbin/` directory